# Upload an entire folder and not separate files - JS

Tags: javascript, upload, directory

I have the following problem, I can upload my photos, file by file, but I have the following doubt, is there any way I can upload a folder with "n" images without having to select all? just by clicking on the folder and selecting it?

[image]

in my case by clicking the folder "pasta imagens".

Comment: As of today, http doesn't allow that. You can though zip and upload. I also don't know if you are talking about http upload or using some other protocol.

Comment: yes man, i'm using the http protocol, thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct folder uploads aren't possible as of today.
But Chrome and Firefox are offering a solution for that, which basically iterates over every file in a certain directory and selects it for the upload.

You just have to set the `directory` flag in your `<input type='file'... />` tag (and the vendor-prefixed `webkitdirectory` for a bigger variety of supported browsers).

[Browser Support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-directory)

```html
<input type='file' webkitdirectory='' directory='' multiple='true' />
```